# How can I add custom graphics in Qt designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm comfortable with C++ but brand new to Qt. I apologize for my ignorance as I'm sure this is a very simple question. I'd like to make a custom clickable widget, basically a push button that is just a black square with Qt designer, but don't have any idea on where to start.

EDIT: after fumbling around I think I'm an epsilon closer.
I created a black_box.png file. In the resource browser I created a new resource and prefix, and added the black_box.png. Any advice from here?

Comment: Start here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for what you want to achieve.

1. You can use custom painting to draw a new button that subclasses `QPushButton`, this is reasonably involved and provides a huge amount of flexibility to build it to your requirements.
2. You can use Qt's stylesheets mechanism to style it, you can get more information on it here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html
3. Or you can set a `QPixmap` of your image to be a button icon, and size your button to match it, there's a good answer on how to do this on this question: [How to set image on QPushButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137805/how-to-set-image-on-qpushbutton)