# Image on a button not working properly in QT

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, qtgui

I believe that I am doing something very wrong with my image buttons. I want to do something as simple as making them change its image whenever I hover over the button or by pressing it. Stylesheets are a bit ambiguous at the moment for me.

Here is a code snip where I think I am doing wrong with it:

```
border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;

hover:{border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Hover.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;};

pressed: {border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;};
```

Does anyone has any idea on what I can do?

---

Another thing that I tried, but to no avail.

```
void MainWindow::on_nucButton_pressed()
{
    ui->nucButton->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Pressed.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}");
   // printf("Work?\n");
}
```

---

Comment: Please add full code with HTML, CSS.

Comment: This is all I have within the stylesheet. No html was used, however, I can give you the xml bits?

Comment: I tried something else.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137805/how-to-set-image-on-qpushbutton

Comment: Does not exactly help me as I tried doing it this way and I managed to get an image working on the button using stylesheets :

border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;

And the others such as hover and pressed do not work which is absolutely bizarre as I had it working in a different project I did sometime ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - just copy pasted the old project code into a new project and everything worked. For some reason my Qt project got bugged and it didn't let me do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ui->nucButton->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Pressed.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"
                             "QLineEdit:hover {border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"
                             "QLineEdit:pressed {border-image: url(:/Data/buttonNUC_Idle.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}");
```