# Qt Designer button image change while keeping windows style?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I can change the image or any other style of a QPushButton in the designer by changing the stylesheet, but any change in the style sheet changes all the other properties.

For instance, when I change the border image everything else is changed and it does not inherit the rest of the properties from the parent (or windows style).

How can I keep the windows style while changing only the image?

Comment: You can show a picture of what you currently get and what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, scopchanov already answered that part. Now the question is how to add an image to a pushbutton form inside QT Designer without changing anything else. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How can I set Styles to a QTabwidget without overwriting existing styles in QT ?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/68252/how-can-i-set-styles-to-a-qtabwidget-without-overwriting-existing-styles-in-qt):

> A style sheet is all or nothing. so if u all apply style sheet, it
>   might sort of reset the look for some widgets and to fix that, you
>   must supply a full stylesheet.

The key parts are:

- A style sheet is all or nothing.
- you must supply a full stylesheet.

You can set an image for the *QPushButton* [from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137805/how-to-set-image-on-qpushbutton/12799623#12799623) or by using *QtDesigner* like this:

1. Select the button
2. In the properties window set the image and the
   size (properties *icon* and *iconSize*).

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way of adding image to the button without using stylesheet? Or can I find windows stylesheet for push button somewhere?

Comment: Is there a way I can do this from inside QT Designer (MSVC)? When I change the QTsth.h form inside visual studio it does not apply the changes?

Comment: @polo what is QTsth.h?

Comment: it is the header file that keeps the code of the QT GUI generated in the designer (which can also be viewed from inside the designer by going to Form -> ViewCode). Its real name in my project is ui_QtGuiApplication2.h

Comment: Thanks @scopchanov, you are a life saver. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set style to the single push button:

```
your_push_button_pointer->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton{background-image: url(:/images/call_up.bmp);}" 
    "QPushButton:hover{background-image: url(:/images/call_hov.bmp);}" 
    "QPushButton:pressed{background-image: url(:/images/call_down.bmp);}");
```

Comment: Yes I did, but on that one push button other properties also change, not only the image.